# ckan.root_path results in 500 internal server error

Tags: ckan

When I try to use the `ckan.root_path` setting the web-application results in a

> 500 Internal server error.  Last line in log: TypeError: object of
>   type 'Locale' has no len()

Is this a bug or do I need to do more configuration?

Installed package `python-ckan_2.5-trusty_amd64.deb` Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The apache error log will give the full stack-trace showing where in the code that error is occurring.